# Problem getting JQuery BBQ to work

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm still new to javascript/jquery, and I want to learn how to utilize a seemingly nice plugin.

I have linked to both jquery and bbq like this:

```
<script src="lib/js/jquery.ba-bbq.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I have inserted this code, that was given in the examples of a simple implementation on Ben Alman's site.

- Can anyone explain to me, where I need to edit? And what kind of divs/tags/classes I would need to test this?

Would be much appreciated.

```
$(function(){

  // Keep a mapping of url-to-container for caching purposes.
  var cache = {
    // If url is '' (no fragment), display this div's content.
    '': $('.bbq-default')
  };

  // Bind an event to window.onhashchange that, when the history state changes,
  // gets the url from the hash and displays either our cached content or fetches
  // new content to be displayed.
  $(window).bind( 'hashchange', function(e) {

    // Get the hash (fragment) as a string, with any leading # removed. Note that
    // in jQuery 1.4, you should use e.fragment instead of $.param.fragment().
    var url = $.param.fragment();

    // Remove .bbq-current class from any previously "current" link(s).
    $( 'a.bbq-current' ).removeClass( 'bbq-current' );

    // Hide any visible ajax content.
    $( '.bbq-content' ).children( ':visible' ).hide();

    // Add .bbq-current class to "current" nav link(s), only if url isn't empty.
    url && $( 'a[href="#' + url + '"]' ).addClass( 'bbq-current' );

    if ( cache[ url ] ) {
      // Since the element is already in the cache, it doesn't need to be
      // created, so instead of creating it again, let's just show it!
      cache[ url ].show();

    } else {
      // Show "loading" content while AJAX content loads.
      $( '.bbq-loading' ).show();

      // Create container for this url's content and store a reference to it in
      // the cache.
      cache[ url ] = $( '<div class="bbq-item"/>' )

        // Append the content container to the parent container.
        .appendTo( '.bbq-content' )

        // Load external content via AJAX. Note that in order to keep this
        // example streamlined, only the content in .infobox is shown. You'll
        // want to change this based on your needs.
        .load( url, function(){
          // Content loaded, hide "loading" content.
          $( '.bbq-loading' ).hide();
        });
    }
  })

  // Since the event is only triggered when the hash changes, we need to trigger
  // the event now, to handle the hash the page may have loaded with.
  $(window).trigger( 'hashchange' );

});
```

Comment: what is the problem that you have? Any errors?

Comment: BTW - you probably want to load jQuery before the bbq plugin. Swap the `script` references around.

Comment: Okay, sorry, maybe I wasn't clear. But my problem is understanding how to use this. Do I need to specify anything to my links? And how do I control where the contents will be placed?

Comment: Switching the `script` references around fixed it. Do you know a way to exclude the `.html` from the url?

Comment: that would be done on the server side and would vary depending on your stack. It would be best answered in another question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly - you should reference jQuery before the bbq plugin.

```
<script src="lib/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/js/jquery.ba-bbq.min.js"></script>
```

The main thing to remember when using the bbq plugin is that instead of manipulating the DOM directly (eg show/hide things/ ajax loading etc), you change the browser url fragment instead and then make the DOM changes in the `hashchange` event. For example:

```
// Hook up a click handler to and anchor
$("#myLink").click(function(){
    $.bbq.pushState("show", true);
});
```

Then in the `hashchange` event, you would check for the `show` url fragment, `$.bbq.getState("show")`, and take the appropriate action.